# How do I support c++11 in Opencv 3 Android NDK

Tags: android, opencv, c++11, android-ndk

Can you help me, please?

I am doing the next changes to support c++11 with opencv 3 in android NDK:

I change from  APP_STL := gnustl_static to  APP_STL := c++_static

Application.mk

```
APP_STL := c++_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -std=c++11 -frtti -fexceptions
APP_ABI :=  armeabi armeabi-v7a mips x86 arm64-v8a x86_64 mips64
APP_PLATFORM := android-14
# use this to select gcc instead of clang
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.9
```

Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
LOCAL_PATH_LIB_DIR:=library/lib/classifier



include $(CLEAR_VARS)


OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=off
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on

OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=SHARED
include ../../../OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_MODULE:= detection_based_tracker

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := DetectionBasedTracker_jni.cpp \
                              library/jniUtils.cpp \
                             ${ LOCAL_PATH_LIB_DIR}/logic.cpp \
                             ${ LOCAL_PATH_LIB_DIR}/logic2.cpp \
 LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)
 LOCAL_LDLIBS     += -llog -ldl -lm -latomic -L$(LOCAL_PATH)/libs/armeabi  
                          - L$(LOCAL_PATH)/libs/armeabi-v7a  -L$(LOCAL_PATH)/libs/mips 
                           -L$(LOCAL_PATH)/libs/x86  -L$(LOCAL_PATH)/libs/arm64-v8a 
                           -L$(LOCAL_PATH)/libs/mips64
                           -L$(LOCAL_PATH)/libs/x86_64
 LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -ljnigraphics -D_LINUX  -DBOOST_HAS_PTHREADS -fexceptions -std=c++11 
                                 -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/  -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/library/lib/pico/ I
LOCAL_CPP_FEATURES :=  exceptions rtti
APP_OPTIM := debug
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

When I compile the Android app with Android NDK r10e. I have the next errores in the Log:

> ' [armeabi-v7a] SharedLibrary  : libdetection_based_tracker.so
>   /android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++
>   -Wl,-soname,libdetection_based_tracker.so -shared --sysroot=/android/sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-8/arch-arm ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/detection_based_tracker/DetectionBasedTracker_jni.o
>   ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/detection_based_tracker/detection-manager/jniUtils.o
>   ../../../OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../3rdparty/libs/armeabi-v7a/liblibpng.a
>   ../../../OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../3rdparty/libs/armeabi-v7a/liblibtiff.a
>   ../../../OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../3rdparty/libs/armeabi-v7a/liblibjasper.a
>   ../../../OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../3rdparty/libs/armeabi-v7a/libIlmImf.a
>   ../../../OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../3rdparty/libs/armeabi-v7a/libtbb.a
>   /android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libs/armeabi-v7a/thumb/libc++_static.a
>   -lgcc -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a -Wl,--fix-cortex-a8  -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now  -L/android/sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/lib -lz -ldl -lm -llog -llog -ldl -lm -latomic -Ljni/libs/armeabi -Ljni/libs/armeabi-v7a -Ljni/libs/mips -Ljni/libs/x86 -Ljni/libs/arm64-v8a -Ljni/libs/mips64 -Ljni/libs/x86_64 -lc -lm -o ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libdetection_based_tracker.so
>   jni/detection-manager/lib/pico/uniqueness2.cpp:240: error: undefined
>   reference to 'cv::DescriptorMatcher::match(cv::_InputArray const&,
>   cv::_InputArray const&, std::__1::vector >&, cv::_InputArray const&) const'
>   jni/detection-manager/lib/pico/motiondetector.cpp:77: error: undefined
>   reference to 'cv::Subdiv2D::insert(std::__1::vector,
>   std::__1::allocator > > const&)'
>   jni/detection-manager/lib/counting-blobs/jniUtils.cpp:995: error:
>   undefined reference to 'cv::imwrite(cv::String const&, cv::_InputArray
>   const&, std::__1::vector > const&)'
>   jni/detection-manager/lib/counting-blobs/jniUtils.cpp:996: error:
>   undefined reference to 'cv::imwrite(cv::String const&, cv::_InputArray
>   const&, std::__1::vector > const&)'
>   jni/detection-manager/lib/counting-blobs/jniUtils.cpp:1004: error:
>   undefined reference to 'cv::imwrite(cv::String const&, cv::_InputArray
>   const&, std::__1::vector > const&)'
>   jni/detection-manager/lib/counting-blobs/jniUtils.cpp:1005: error:
>   undefined reference to 'cv::imwrite(cv::String const&, cv::_InputArray
>   const&, std::__1::vector > const&)'
>   jni/detection-manager/lib/counting-blobs/jniUtils.cpp:1153: error:
>   undefined reference to
>   'cv::DescriptorMatcher::knnMatch(cv::_InputArray const&,
>   cv::_InputArray const&, std::__1::vector >,
>   std::__1::allocator > > >&, int, cv::_InputArray const&,
>   bool) const'
>   ../../../OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_objdetect.a(cascadedetect.cpp.o):cascadedetect.cpp:function
>   cv::LBPEvaluator::setWindow(cv::Point_, int): error: undefined
>   reference to 'std::__throw_out_of_range(char const*)'
>   ../../../OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_objdetect.a(cascadedetect.cpp.o):cascadedetect.cpp:function
>   cv::HaarEvaluator::setWindow(cv::Point_, int): error: undefined
>   reference to 'std::__throw_out_of_range(char const*)'
>   ../../../OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_objdetect.a(cascadedetect.cpp.o):cascadedetect.cpp:function
>   cv::HaarEvaluator::computeChannels(int, cv::_InputArray const&):
>   error: undefined reference to 'std::__throw_out_of_range(char const*)'
>   ../../../OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_objdetect.a(cascadedetect.cpp.o):cascadedetect.cpp:function
>   cv::LBPEvaluator::computeChannels(int, cv::_InputArray const&): error:
>   undefined reference to 'std::__throw_out_of_range(char const*)'
>   ../../../OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_objdetect.a(cascadedetect.cpp.o):cascadedetect.cpp:function
>   std::vector >::resize(unsigned int, int):
>   error: undefined reference to 'std::__throw_length_error(char const*)'
>   ../../../OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_objdetect.a(cascadedetect.cpp.o):cascadedetect.cpp:function
>   std::vector >::resize(unsigned int,
>   double): error: undefined reference to 'std::__throw_length_error(char
>   const*)'
>   ../../../OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_objdetect.a(cascadedetect.cpp.o):cascadedetect.cpp:function
>   std::vector >::reserve(unsigned int):
>   error: undefined reference to 'std::__throw_length_error(char const*)'
>   ../../../OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_objdetect.a(cascadedetect.cpp.o):cascadedetect.cpp:function
>   std::vector
>
> > ::reserve(unsigned int): error: undefined reference to 'std::__throw_length_error(char const*)'
>
> ../../../OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_flann.a(miniflann.cpp.o):miniflann.cpp:function
>   cvflann::LshIndex >::getNeighbors(float const*,
>   cvflann::ResultSet&): error: undefined reference to
>   'std::__throw_bad_cast()'
>   ../../../OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_flann.a(miniflann.cpp.o):miniflann.cpp:function
>   cvflann::LshIndex >::getNeighbors(float const*,
>   cvflann::ResultSet&): error: undefined reference to 'std::cerr'
>   ../../../OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_flann.a(miniflann.cpp.o):miniflann.cpp:function
>   std::_Rb_tree > >,
>   std::_Select1st > > >, std::less,
>   std::allocator > > >
>
> > ::_M_insert_unique_(std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator > >
> >     , std::pair > > const&): error: undefined reference
> >     to 'std::_Rb_tree_increment(std::_Rb_tree_node_base*)'
> >     ../../../OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_flann.a(miniflann.cpp.o):miniflann.cpp:function
> >     cvflann::AutotunedIndex >::buildIndex(): error:
> >     undefined reference to 'std::basic_ostringstream, std::allocator
> >     ::basic_ostringstream(std::_Ios_Openmode)' ../../../OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_flann.a(miniflann.cpp.o):miniflann.cpp:function
> >     cvflann::AutotunedIndex >::buildIndex(): error:
> >     undefined reference to 'std::basic_stringbuf, std::allocator >::str() const' .
> >     /android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld:
> >     the vtable symbol may be undefined because the class is missing its
> >     key function
> >     ../../../OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_flann.a(miniflann.cpp.o):miniflann.cpp:function
> >     cvflann::AutotunedIndex >::buildIndex(): error:
> >     undefined reference to 'vtable for std::basic_stringbuf, std::allocator >'
>
> /android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld:
>   the vtable symbol may be undefined because the class is missing its
>   key function
>   ../../../OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function
>   std::basic_stringbuf,
>   std::allocator >::~basic_stringbuf(): error: undefined reference
>   to 'vtable for std::basic_streambuf >'
>   /android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld:
>   the vtable symbol may be undefined because the class is missing its
>   key function
>   ../../../OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function
>   std::basic_stringbuf,
>   std::allocator >::~basic_stringbuf(): error: undefined reference
>   to 'std::locale::~locale()'
>   ../../../OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function
>   std::basic_stringbuf,
>   std::allocator >::~basic_stringbuf(): error: undefined reference
>   to 'std::string::_Rep::_S_empty_rep_storage'
>   ../../../OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function
>   std::basic_stringbuf,
>   std::allocator >::~basic_stringbuf(): error: undefined reference
>   to 'vtable for std::basic_stringbuf,
>   std::allocator >'
>   /android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld:
>   the vtable symbol may be undefined because the class is missing its
>   key function
>   ../../../OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function
>   std::basic_stringbuf,
>   std::allocator >::~basic_stringbuf(): error: undefined reference
>   to 'vtable for std::basic_streambuf >'
>   /android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld:
>   the vtable symbol may be undefined because the class is missing its
>   key function
>   ../../../OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function
>   std::string cv::ocl::kerToStr(cv::Mat const&): error: undefined
>   reference to 'std::basic_ostringstream,
>   std::allocator >::basic_ostringstream(std::_Ios_Openmode)' .
>
> ../../../OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function
>   cv::ocl::Context::Impl::setDefault(): error: undefined reference to
>   'std::string::find(char const*, unsigned int, unsigned int) const'
>   ../../../OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function
>   cv::ocl::Context::Impl::setDefault(): error: undefined reference to
>   'std::string::_M_leak_hard()'
>   ../../../OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function
>   cv::ocl::Context::Impl::setDefault(): error: undefined reference to
>   'std::basic_string, std::allocator
>
> > ::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator const&)' ../../../OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function
> >     cv::ocl::Context::Impl::setDefault(): error: undefined reference to
> >     'std::basic_string, std::allocator
> >     ::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator const&)' ../../../OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function
> >     cv::ocl::Context::Impl::setDefault(): error: undefined reference to
> >     'std::basic_string, std::allocator
> >     ::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator const&)' ../../../OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function
> >     cv::ocl::Context::Impl::setDefault(): error: undefined reference to
> >     'std::string::_M_leak_hard()'
> >     ../../../OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function
> >     cv::ocl::Context::Impl::setDefault(): error: undefined reference to
> >     'std::string::_M_leak_hard()'
> >     ../../../OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function
> >     cv::ocl::Context::Impl::setDefault(): error: undefined reference to
> >     'std::string::_M_leak_hard()'
> >     ../../../OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function
> >     cv::ocl::Context::Impl::setDefault(): error: undefined reference to
> >     'std::string::compare(char const*) const'
> >     ../../../OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function
> >     cv::ocl::Context::Impl::setDefault(): error: undefined reference to
> >     'std::string::compare(char const*) const'
> >     ../../../OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function
> >     cv::ocl::Context::Impl::setDefault(): error: undefined reference to
> >     'std::string::compare(char const*) const'
> >     ../../../OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function
> >     cv::ocl::Context::Impl::setDefault(): error: undefined reference to
> >     'std::string::find(char const*, unsigned int, unsigned int) const'
> >     ../../../OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function
> >     cv::ocl::Context::Impl::setDefault(): error: undefined reference to
> >     'std::string::compare(char const*) const'
> >     ../../../OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function
> >     cv::ocl::Context::Impl::setDefault(): error: undefined reference to
> >     'std::basic_ostream >& std::endl >(std::basic_ostream >&)'
> >     ../../../OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function
> >     cv::ocl::Context::Impl::setDefault(): error: undefined reference to
> >     'std::basic_ostream >& std::endl >(std::basic_ostream >&)'
> >     ../../../OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function
> >     cv::ocl::Context::Impl::setDefault(): error: undefined reference to
> >     'std::basic_ostream >& std::endl >(std::basic_ostream >&)'
> >     ../../../OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function
> >     cv::ocl::Context::Impl::setDefault(): error: undefined reference to
> >     'std::basic_ostream >& std::endl >(std::basic_ostream >&)'
> >     ../../../OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function
> >     cv::ocl::Context::Impl::setDefault(): error: undefined reference to
> >     'std::string::assign(std::string const&)'
> >     ../../../OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function
> >     cv::ocl::Context::Impl::setDefault(): error: undefined reference to
> >     'std::string::assign(std::string const&)'
> >     ../../../OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function
> >     cv::ocl::OpenCLBufferPoolImpl::_allocateBufferEntry(cv::ocl::CLBufferEntry&,
> >     unsigned int): error: undefined reference to
> >     'std::__detail::_List_node_base::_M_hook(std::__detail::_List_node_base*)'
> >     ../../../OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../3rdparty/libs/armeabi-v7a/libIlmImf.a(half.cpp.o):half.cpp:function
> >     operator>>(std::istream&, half&): error: undefined reference to
> >     'std::istream& std::istream::_M_extract(float&)'
> >     ../../../OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../3rdparty/libs/armeabi-v7a/libIlmImf.a(ImfChannelList.cpp.o):ImfChannelList.cpp:function
> >     Imf::ChannelList::operator[](char const*): error: undefined reference
> >     to 'std::basic_stringstream,
> >     std::allocator >::basic_stringstream(std::_Ios_Openmode)'
> >     ../../../OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../3rdparty/libs/armeabi-v7a/libIlmImf.a(ImfChannelList.cpp.o):ImfChannelList.cpp:function
> >     Imf::ChannelList::operator[](char const*): error: undefined reference
> >     to 'std::basic_stringstream,
> >     std::allocator >::~basic_stringstream()' .
> >     ../../../OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../3rdparty/libs/armeabi-v7a/libtbb.a(tbb_misc.cpp.o):tbb_misc.cpp:function
> >     tbb::internal::throw_exception_v4(tbb::internal::exception_id): error:
> >     undefined reference to 'std::out_of_range::out_of_range(std::string
> >     const&)'
> >     ../../../OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../3rdparty/libs/armeabi-v7a/libtbb.a(tbb_misc.cpp.o):tbb_misc.cpp:function
> >     tbb::internal::throw_exception_v4(tbb::internal::exception_id): error:
> >     undefined reference to 'std::range_error::range_error(std::string
> >     const&)'
> >     ../../../OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../3rdparty/libs/armeabi-v7a/libtbb.a(tbb_misc.cpp.o):tbb_misc.cpp:function
> >     tbb::internal::throw_exception_v4(tbb::internal::exception_id): error:
> >     undefined reference to 'std::range_error::range_error(std::string
> >     const&)'
> >     ../../../OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../3rdparty/libs/armeabi-v7a/libtbb.a(tbb_misc.cpp.o):tbb_misc.cpp:function
> >     tbb::internal::throw_exception_v4(tbb::internal::exception_id): error:
> >     undefined reference to 'std::runtime_error::runtime_error(std::string
> >     const&)'
> >     ../../../OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../3rdparty/libs/armeabi-v7a/libtbb.a(tbb_misc.cpp.o):tbb_misc.cpp:function
> >     tbb::internal::throw_exception_v4(tbb::internal::exception_id): error:
> >     undefined reference to 'std::runtime_error::runtime_error(std::string
> >     const&)'
> >     ../../../OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../3rdparty/libs/armeabi-v7a/libtbb.a(tbb_misc.cpp.o):tbb_misc.cpp:function
> >     tbb::internal::throw_exception_v4(tbb::internal::exception_id): error:
> >     undefined reference to 'std::out_of_range::out_of_range(std::string
> >     const&)'
> >     ../../../OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../3rdparty/libs/armeabi-v7a/libtbb.a(tbb_misc.cpp.o):tbb_misc.cpp:function
> >     tbb::internal::throw_exception_v4(tbb::internal::exception_id): error:
> >     undefined reference to 'std::out_of_range::out_of_range(std::string
> >     const&)'
> >     ../../../OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../3rdparty/libs/armeabi-v7a/libtbb.a(tbb_misc.cpp.o):tbb_misc.cpp:function
> >     tbb::internal::throw_exception_v4(tbb::internal::exception_id): error:
> >     undefined reference to
> >     'std::invalid_argument::invalid_argument(std::string const&)'
> >     ../../../OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../3rdparty/libs/armeabi-v7a/libtbb.a(tbb_misc.cpp.o):tbb_misc.cpp:function
> >     tbb::internal::throw_exception_v4(tbb::internal::exception_id): error:
> >     undefined reference to 'std::length_error::length_error(std::string
> >     const&)'
> >     ../../../OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../3rdparty/libs/armeabi-v7a/libtbb.a(tbb_misc.cpp.o):tbb_misc.cpp:function
> >     tbb::internal::throw_exception_v4(tbb::internal::exception_id): error:
> >     undefined reference to 'std::out_of_range::out_of_range(std::string 
> >     const&)'   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status   make: ***
> >     [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libdetection_based_tracker.so] Error 1

Comment: which ABI flavor produces these errors?

Comment: also, I would recommend to switch to `OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=STATIC`

Comment: also, note that 64-bit ABIs are not compatible with **android-14** APP_PLATFORM.

Comment: Hi , ABI flavor is in the first in the compilation process: [armeabi], just when after of this line, I have the next errores:

Comment: [armeabi] SharedLibrary  : libdetection_based_tracker.so

Comment: I changed in Android.mk file the  OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=STATIC and APP_PLATFORM := android-8 and when I compile I have same errores

Comment: sorry, to support 64-bit you need android-21 or higher! Not android-8

Comment: But let's leave 64-bit architectures aside for a moment. I would suggest to start with one, and the most popular (and the one that you most likely can actually test) is armeabi-v7a. CHoose it in Application.mk and run `ndk-build V=1`. Post the resulting log (it may be quite long).

Comment: [This](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/8742#issuecomment-385553011) might solve the issue.